# can't select database wordpress error

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, heroku

I'm setting up a wordpress site through heroku. I get the following error at this url: http://aaaa.herokuapp.com/wp-admin/

> Can't select database:
>
> We were able to connect to the database server (which means your
> username and password is okay) but not able to select the
> heroku_ddddddd database.
>
> Are you sure it exists? Does the user
> user_nnnnnnn have permission to use the heroku_ddddddd
> database?
>
> On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with
> your username, so it would be like username_heroku_ddddddd.
> Could that be the problem?

In my wp-config.php file, I have this database connection code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["DATABASE_URL"])) {
 $db = parse_url($_SERVER["DATABASE_URL"]);
 define("DB_NAME", "heroku_ddddddd");
 define("DB_USER", "user_nnnnnnn");
 define("DB_PASSWORD", "pass_ppppp");
 define("DB_HOST", "us-cdbr-east-04.cleardb.com");
}
else {
 die("Your heroku DATABASE_URL does not appear to be correctly specified.");
}
```

I can login to the database using mysql from the command line, `mysql --user=user_nnnnnnn --password=pass_ppppp --host=us-cdbr-east-04.cleardb.com --database=heroku_ddddddd`

Comment: Dude ... change your question you just gave everyone reading access to your database...

Comment: In Heroku/server properties, is the database name written in the Maintenance DB field?