# Can't select database error in WordPress localhost on WAMP Server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, debugging, localhost, wampserver

I’m following this Lynda.com tutorial (*WordPress – Building Themes from Scratch Using Underscores (2017)*) and haven’t gotten very far. I’ve installed a blank WordPress install on localhost using **WAMP Server** and I downloaded and installed the underscores theme. But for some reason when I am trying to launch the website I am getting this error:

> Can’t select database
>
> We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the lynda_under17_040518 database.
>
> Are you sure it exists?
>
> Does the user root have permission to use the lynda_under17_040518 database?
>   On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like username_lynda_under17_040518. Could that be the problem?
>
> If you don’t know how to set up a database you should contact your host. If all else fails you may find help at the WordPress Support Forums.

### Here is what i know

- The database exists and I can run SQL commands on it in phpMyAdmin.
- My user is root
- Host is localhost
- Database is lynda_under17_040518
- root has all privileges to database (as verified in phpMyAdmin)
- Other local websites on the same WAMPServer work just fine

[This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261018/we-were-able-to-connect-to-the-database-server-error-in-wordpress/#answer-35262780) says to put `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` in wp-config.php which I’ve done. It also says:

> “the debug.log file will be in wp-content.”

I don't see any debug log even though I’ve restarted all services in WAMP and refreshed the browser.

### Other Links I Consulted

I reviewed the info on these pages, but they didn't really help for my situation.

- [can't select database wordpress error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776473/cant-select-database-wordpress-error)
- [Can't select database - Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801992/cant-select-database-wordpress)
- https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/discussion/-KP4_87InltfL9P6rf-J/cant-select-database-wordpress-error
- https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-a-database-in-mysql/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/263868/how-to-know-all-the-users-that-can-access-a-database-mysql/263936

Where is my debug log and how can i get my local website running?

Comment: Some apps have difficulty with database names over 16 characters (yours is). If you shorten the database name, do you still get the same error?

Comment: @MichaelW. Let me try it and I'll report back.

Comment: @MichaelW. It worked! I shortened renamed the db to "hume" and updated wp-config and after restarted my server I could finally see my database! If you put your comment as an answer I will accept it as the the solution.

Comment: Glad I could help! Answer posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though SQL and its ilk will allow database names that are very long, a lot of applications (such as cPanel) will only recognize database names that are 16 characters or less. I suspect that your database name (lynda_under17_040518) is simply too long for WAMP and/or WordPress to recognize and will work correctly if the database name is shortened.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using an alternate port (something other than 3306), so I had to follow these instructions:
https://codex.wordpress.org/sk:Editing_wp-config.php#MySQL_Alternate_Port